# Update the value of a ng-model on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I would like to do a mail system with auto-completion.

1. The user click on the input
2. The list of users appears below the input
3. The user can pick a name up
4. The name of the user goes inside the input.

Theses steps works well, but as soon the user start to type a letter, the filter is applied and the proposal list is modified. If the users click on a name, it doesn't fill the input, therefore the value "destinataire" contains the name.

I'm probably missing something with the update of the ng-model value.

Any help appreciated!

**My HTML :**

```
  <div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-email placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="search" ng-init="repertoire=0" ng-click="repertoire=1" ng-model="destinataire"  placeholder="Destinataire" >
      </label>
  </div>
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label commentaireeval" ng-show="repertoire==0">
      <input type="text" ng-model="nouveaumessage" placeholder="Votre message ...">
  </label>
  <div id="repertoiredestinataire" ng-show="repertoire==1" ng-click="repertoire=0">
    <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-icon-right" ng-repeat="patient in patients | filter:{name:destinataire} | orderBy:'+name'" type="item-text-wrap" ng-click="choixdudestinataire(patient.name); destinataire=patient.name">
    {{patient.name}}
    </ion-item>
```

**My Controller:**

```
.controller('ChatNouveauCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Chats', 'Patients', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats, Patients) {
    $scope.patients = Patients.all();
    $scope.choixdudestinataire = function(NewDestinataire){
    $scope.destinataire = NewDestinataire;
    };
}])
```

1. The input after the click, with the list:
   [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQP8O.png)
2. If the user click on an item without writing (it's works!):
   [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFXBn.png)
3. If the user start to type a letter, the filter is applied (it's works!).But if the user click on an item after writing, the input doesn't contain the chosen name.

Comment: Can you be more clear as to what isn't working and what is supposed ti do. I tested it and it seems okay.

Comment: I think it's a problem of scope use $ctrl with both ng-model values, see if that helps...

Comment: @theblindprophet When the user pick up a name from the list, the chosen name goes inside the input. But, if he starts to type a letter to use the filter and if he pick a name up from the new list, the name is not replaced by the chosen name. The input contains only the few letters typed, like the ng-model was not updated with the new value. Please have a look on the new  edit.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5770/

Comment: I didn't think that the div with the "ng-controller" was so important. I thought this was automatic.